# R RGtk2 gdf: How do we identify the row we are

Tags: r

```
library(gWidgets)
options(guiToolkit = "RGtk2")
```

QUESTION: Is there a way to identify the row we are in gdf ?

REMARK: svalue returns the value of the first column of the row we are.
If the first column has two same values then how do we identify the row we are ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try svalue with index=TRUE, that should do it.